# KeyError while crawling websites for keyword and status

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm currently trying to put two things together when checking multiple websites from my input CSV file:

1. Check HTTP status
2. Check if Website displays specific keyword

then save the results to a new CSV file.

My input.csv:

```
id    url
1     https://example123.com
2     https://envato.com/blog/30-outstanding-coming-soon-and-under-construction-website-templates/
3     https://mundoshoponline.com
```

My Code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio
import re

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/my/input.csv')

#my csv has urls in the 1st column
urls = df.T.values.tolist()[1]
results = {}
status = []

async def scrape(url):
 try:
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=(3, 6))
    r.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    #all keywords to check on the website
    data = {
    "coming soon": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("coming soon", re.I)),
    "Opening Soon": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Opening Soon", re.I)),
    "Forbidden": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Forbidden", re.I)),
    "Page not found": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Page not found", re.I)),
    "Under Construction": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Under Construction", re.I)),
    "Currently Unavailable": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Currently Unavailable", re.I))}
    results[url] = data
 #check for http status and save to status list 
 except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.Timeout):
        status.append("Down")
 except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        status.append("Other")
 else:
        status.append("OK")


async def main():
    await asyncio.wait([scrape(url) for url in urls])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()

comingList= []
openingList = []
forbiddenList= []
notfoundList = []
underList = []
currentlyList = []
#mark x if there are any hits for specific keyword
for url in results:
    comingList.append("x" if len(results[url]["coming soon"]) > 0 else "")
    openingList.append("x" if len(results[url]["Opening Soon"]) > 0 else "")
    forbiddenList.append("x" if len(results[url]["Forbidden"]) > 0 else "")
    notfoundList.append("x" if len(results[url]["Page not found"]) > 0 else "")           
    underList.append("x" if len(results[url]["Under Construction"]) > 0 else "")
    currentlyList.append("x" if len(results[url]["Currently Unavailable"]) > 0 else "")


df["comingSoon"] = pd.DataFrame(comingList, columns=['comingSoon'])
df["openingSoon"] = pd.DataFrame(openingList, columns=['openingSoon'])
df["forbidden"] = pd.DataFrame(forbiddenList, columns=['forbidden'])
df["notfound2"] = pd.DataFrame(notfoundList, columns=['notfound2'])
df["underConstruction"] = pd.DataFrame(underList, columns=['underConstruction'])
df["currentlyUnavailable"] = pd.DataFrame(currentlyList, columns=['currentlyUnavailable'])
df['status'] = status

print(df)

df.to_csv('path/to/my/output.csv', index=False)
```

However, whenever I run the above script with `for url in urls:`
for some of my urls it throws this error and script breaks and output.csv is not generated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/myscan.py", line 51, in <module>
    comingList.append("x" if len(results[url]["coming soon"]) > 0 else "")
KeyError: 'http://example123.com'
```

and when running it with `for url in results:` output.csv is as follows:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

seems erroneous as first row has keywords marked as present (comingSoon, underConstruction columns) + status column = Down. But website doesn't contain 'coming soon' or 'under construction' strings.

Would someone be able to help me with this? I believe there might be an issue in my loop or try/except part of the code. I'm happy to provide more information if the above is not sufficient. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you are iterating over the whole `urls` which some of which may have failed and therefore does not exist in your `results` as a key.

A much safer way to do this is to iterate over the subset of urls that you are sure have succeeded and have a key in `results`, so instead of

```
for url in urls:
```

you could make it

```
for url in results:
```

To make the final results consistent with the input order of your urls:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio
import re

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
df = pd.read_csv('./input.csv')

#my csv has urls in the 4th column
urls = [ 'example123.com', 'https://envato.com/blog/30-outstanding-coming-soon-and-under-construction-website-templates/', 'http://alotechgear.com'] 
results = {}
status = {}
async def scrape(url):
 try:
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=(3, 6))
    r.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    #all keywords to check on the website
    data = {
    "coming soon": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("coming soon", re.I)),
    "Opening Soon": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Opening Soon", re.I)),
    "Forbidden": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Forbidden", re.I)),
    "Page not found": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Page not found", re.I)),
    "Under Construction": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Under Construction", re.I)),
    "Currently Unavailable": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Currently Unavailable", re.I))}
    results[url] = data
 #check for http status and save to status list 
 except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.Timeout, requests.exceptions.MissingSchema):
     status[url] = "Down"
 except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
     status[url] = "Other"
 else:
     status[url] = "OK"


async def main():
    await asyncio.wait([scrape(url) for url in urls])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()

comingList= []
openingList = []
forbiddenList= []
notfoundList = []
underList = []
currentlyList = []
statusList = []
#mark x if there are any hits for specific keyword

for url in urls:
    if(not results.get(url)):
        statusList.append(status.get(url))
        notfoundList.append("x")
        comingList.append("-")
        openingList.append("-")
        forbiddenList.append("-")
        underList.append("-")
        currentlyList.append("-")
    else:
        statusList.append(status.get(url))
        comingList.append("x" if len(results[url].get("coming soon")) > 0 else "-")
        openingList.append("x" if len(results[url].get("Opening Soon")) > 0 else "-")
        forbiddenList.append("x" if len(results[url].get("Forbidden")) > 0 else "-")
        notfoundList.append("x" if len(results[url].get("Page not found")) > 0 else "-")           
        underList.append("x" if len(results[url].get("Under Construction")) > 0 else "-")
        currentlyList.append("x" if len(results[url].get("Currently Unavailable")) > 0 else "-")

df["comingSoon"] = pd.DataFrame(comingList, columns=['comingSoon'])
df["openingSoon"] = pd.DataFrame(openingList, columns=['openingSoon'])
df["forbidden"] = pd.DataFrame(forbiddenList, columns=['forbidden'])
df["notfound2"] = pd.DataFrame(notfoundList, columns=['notfound2'])
df["underConstruction"] = pd.DataFrame(underList, columns=['underConstruction'])
df["currentlyUnavailable"] = pd.DataFrame(currentlyList, columns=['currentlyUnavailable'])
df['status'] = pd.DataFrame(statusList, columns=['Status'])

print(df)
df.to_csv('./output.csv', index=False)
```

sample result:

```
                                           id    url comingSoon openingSoon forbidden notfound2 underConstruction currentlyUnavailable status
0                       1     https://example123.com          -           -         -         x                 -                    -   Down
1  2     https://envato.com/blog/30-outstanding-c...          x           -         -         -                 x                    -     OK
2                  3     https://mundoshoponline.com          -           -         -         x                 -                    -   Down
```

Comment: Hi Kareem, thanks for this hint! I've tried changing urls to results and script steps have been successfully completed, but then when scanning those 3 testing pages: https://example123.com, https://envato.com/blog/30-outstanding-coming-soon-and-under-construction-website-templates/, https://mundoshoponline.com it gives me results that aren't accurate in my output.csv. For the first website that is down it would mark also that it contains 'coming soon' and 'under construction'. In this case it should only say 'Down' in the status column in my output. Would you know what i'm doing wrong?thanks

Comment: could you provide a sample csv file input to reproduce ?

Comment: H Kareem just added input.csv and how the output.csv looks after running code with results instead of urls. Let me know if I can provide anything else. thank you!

Comment: Check my answer, I updated it with sample code to keep your output csv consistent with the input.

Comment: I've tried your answer, but still found some discrepancies. Please have a look at the end of my post I added there 'EDIT' paragraph and thanks for your help so far!

Comment: The problem is that you are using async in fetching urls and assigning their statuses 
so the urls arrray could be ```['url1', 'url2']```
but actually the statuses array would be filled in the order of their response, if url2 responded first then it would be
```['status2', 'status2']```

Comment: Just to clarify, should I change this bit to something else `urls = df.T.values.tolist()[1]` or would I need to change something in this bit of my code `async def main():
    await asyncio.wait([scrap(url) for url in urls])` and/or I would have to get rid of async step completely and replace with something else? Thanks!

Comment: no you need to assign each status to its url as dict instead of appending in an array

Comment: the line ```df.T.values.tolist()[1]``` works fine to get you the urls if your csv is comma separated, either add a comma between values in csv or define the separator in your ```read_csv``` function

Comment: thanks for all your help Kareem! It works perfectly now :-)